# how does % work in Makefile when there is a rule for more specific pattern for that %?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile inside which are these rules(shown only parts).

```
OBJ=gemm.o utils.o cuda.o ...
ASMS        =  abts_crt2.S
OBJ+= $(ASMS:.S=.o)
LDS         = ldabts.lds

OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJ))
DEPS = $(wildcard src/*.h) Makefile

$(OBJDIR)%.o : %.S                 # <---- rule 1
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -D__ASSEMBLY__ $< -o $@
$(OBJDIR)%.lds : %.lds.S                # <------ rule 2
    $(CC) -E $(CFLAGS) -D__START__=$(START_BASE) -m32 -P -C -Usparc $< -o $@
test2: $(OBJS) $(LDS)                   # <----- rule 3
    $(CC) $(COMMON) $(CFLAGS) $< -T $(LDS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I have a file called ldabts.lds.S in the VPATH and I wanted it to be processed by rule 2. But when I do `make test2`, rule 1 is kicked in and it tries to make objs/ldabts.lds.o from ldabts.lds.S and gives me various errors. Of course if I do `make obj/ldabts.lds`, it works fine using rule 2. How can I prevent ldabts.lds.S file from being processed by rule 1?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], we don't know the exact content of `OBJDIR` or `OBJ`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it backwards -- what matters is the *target* -- the pattern before the colon.  So there's no commonality between these patterns; they match completely different targets.  If you tell make to build objs/ldabts.lds.o, it will try to use the first rule as that is what matches (and its the only rule that matches, from what you've shown).  If you don't want that, don't try to make objs/ldabts.lds.o

From your additional edit, it looks like the problem is that you have `test2` depend on `ldabt.lds`, which has no `$(OBJDIR)` prefix.  Because that prefix isn't there, your rule 2 does not apply and it looks for some other way to build it.  It sees your rule 1, and combines that with the builtin rule `%: %.o` to build it that way.  Add the `$(OBJDIR)` prefix (either in the definition of `LDS` or elsewhere with `$(addprefix`), and it should work fine.

Comment: I added some codes in my question. target test2 requres updating ldabts.lds and I have given the rule to make ldabts.lds from ldabts.lds.S in rule 2. But somehow rule 1 is applied for ldabts.lds.S because it can apply the rule I guess. I verfieid the error messages are coming from applying rule 1 to ldabts.lds.S. Do you know how I can prevent rule 1 from being applied to ldabts.lds.S ?